# my code is displaying wrong output for factorial

Tags: java

```
class TestClass {

    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {

        long n = 1;
        long ans = 1;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        long N = s.nextInt();
        long M = 1000000007;

        for (int i=1; i<=N; i++) {
            ans = (ans*i) % M;
        }
        System.out.println(ans);
    }
}
```

for 5! it is giving correct answer but when the value is more i am getting wrong output

Comment: Show Input, Output, expected Output. BTW: read about Java Naminc Convention. variable names should start with lower case letter

Comment: Why do you have `%M` (actually why do you have `M` at all)?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch some sort of attempt at overflow protection

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-exactly-is-print-it-modulo-10-9-+-7-in-competitive-programming-websites @Elliott Frisch

Comment: Like what wrong output with what input ?

Comment: Let med guess, 1000000007 is a constant from some online coding contest site like Hackerrank, for example?

Comment: [What exactly is "print it modulo 10^9 + 7" in competitive programming websites?](https://www.quora.com/What-exactly-is-print-it-modulo-10-9-+-7-in-competitive-programming-websites?share=1) Or [“Output the Answer modulo 10^9 + 7”](https://codeaccepted.wordpress.com/2014/02/15/output-the-answer-modulo-109-7/).

Comment: On my computer your program prints correct factorials up to the factorial of 12 (479001600). The factorial of 13 is 6227020800, which is more than your `M`, so this is output as 227020758.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `long M = 1000000007;` is buggy. (Is it a throwback to the old C ways of doing this for a narrower type?) Effectively a multiple of `1000000007` will be subtracted to pull a number greater or equal to that back into range: and the result of that will be nonsense.

Don't do that. Rely on Java to wrap-around for you as a last resort.

Then just adopt one of the rules of the `long` type: since the range of `long` is fixed in Java, the largest factorial number you can evaluate using that type is also fixed and happens to be `20!`:

```
if (N > 20){
    /*an overflow will occur so inform the user of your program*/
}
```

Do that and drop the `M` entirely.

Comment: Indeed, 12! is the last value that would fit with this filtrer.
`12! : 479001600 &
13! : 6227020800`. And of course, BigInteger are always a solution for the `N >= 20`

Answer (score 0):

Its basically depending on the number M with which you are doing modular operation. try by increasing M like long M = 100000000000007L will generate more valid factorial.